# CSV: when unicode is not unicode?

Tags: python, csv, unicode, python-2.x

Why `writerow()` says I'm passing `str`, when I'm passing `unicode`?

```
import io
import csv

with io.open('test.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    x = [unicode(v, 'utf8') for v in ['id:ID', 'pos:string', 'definition:string', ':LABEL']]
    print x
    print type(x[0])
    writer.writerow(x)
```

---

```
[u'id:ID', u'pos:string', u'definition:string', u':LABEL']
<type 'unicode'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "testcsv.py", line 9, in <module>
     writer.writerow(x)
  TypeError: write() argument 1 must be unicode, not str
```

Comment: I don't think the `csv` module in Python 2.x handles Unicode. See the **Note** in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv).

Comment: I agree it's confusing – I think the following is happening: the `writer.writerow()` call coerces `x[0]` to `str` and passes it to `f.write()` (the stream you opened with `io.open`). The traceback doesn't show this clearly though.

Comment: Python handling of text, and CSV files in particular, are one thing that really got fixed in Python 3. You should really consider using Python 3 instead.

Answer (score 3):

The `csv` module in python 2 does not handle `unicode`. The python 2 documentation [gives an example](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) of how to create your own unicode csv handlers instead.

A better option would be to install the [`backports.csv`](https://pypi.org/project/backports.csv/) module, which allows your python 2 code to use the newer python 3 `csv` api, which handles unicode.

After installing the library using `pip install backports.csv`, this code works in python 2:

```py
>>> import io
>>> from backports import csv
>>> with io.open('test.csv', 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
>>>     writer = csv.writer(f)
>>>     x = [unicode(v, 'utf8') for v in ['id:ID', 'pos:string', 'definition:string', ':LABEL']]
>>>     print x
>>>     print type(x[0])
>>>     writer.writerow(x)
[u'id:ID', u'pos:string', u'definition:string', u':LABEL']
<type 'unicode'>

>>> with io.open('test.csv', encoding="utf-8") as f:
>>>     print f.read()
id:ID,pos:string,definition:string,:LABEL
```

Comment: Of course, and even better option is to use Python 3 altogether.